# Order by sorted array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that contains a table like the following (automatically sorted by "Name" column)

```
  Name         Open Num   Total Num
-----------------------------------
Doe, John         0          0
Smith, Sarah      4          3
Tyler, Rose       7          8
```

The second `tr` would look like this:

```
<tr id="1"><td class="N">Smith, Sarah</td><td class="O">4</td><td class="T">3</td></tr>
```

Where the row ID is a counter (first row = 0, second = 1, third = 2, etc.) and the cell class is to grab the column using jQuery (`$(".O")` gives `Open Num` column)

I'm trying to get the table to sort based off of the numerical columns (`Open Num` and `Total Num`).  So output would look like this (sorted by `Open Num` or `Total Num`):

```
  Name         Open Num   Total Num
-----------------------------------
Tyler, Rose       7          8
Smith, Sarah      4          3
Doe, John         0          0
```

So far, I store the numbers into an array `arrQuick` and I store the row number in a different array `rowCount`.  I then use the Quick Sort method to sort the data, at the same time sorting the second array, which works perfectly.  So now I have the sorted data and the order that my rows should be in.

**The Problem**

I cannot figure out how to get the table rows to update correctly.

So far I have this.

```
for(var i=0;i<rowCount.length;i++){
    var tmpHolder=$("#"+i).html();
    $("#"+i).html($("#"+rowCount[rowCount.length-(i+1)]).html());
    $("#"+rowCount[rowCount.length-(i+1)]).html(tmpHolder);
}
```

When stepping through I can see that initially the updating is working.  However, eventually it gets to some point rows are getting updated to places they shouldn't be and I'm not sure why.

Comment: IDs shouldn't be only numeric.

Comment: Ids can be numeric in HTML5

Comment: Why not?  The only thing the row id is used for is this jQuery updating, so making them numeric and sequential means I can easily have the for loop setup.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ID's being only numeric, however in this case an ID isn't needed at all.

Comment: Perhaps useful is this library of mine: http://phrogz.net/JS/Array.prototype.sortBy.js It allows cascading sorts of arrays of objects generically. However, it does not (as-is) support descending sorts.

Comment: Also, though it's old and does not support cascading sort, see: http://phrogz.net/JS/sorTable/sorTable_docs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the rows based on the values of table cells. The following method accepts a className of the cells and sorts the rows based on the text contents of that cells.

```
$.fn.sortTable = function(cls) {
    this.find('tr').sort(function(a, b){
       return $(a).find('td.'+cls).text() > $(b).find('td.' + cls).text();
    }).appendTo(this.find('tbody'));
}

$('table').sortTable('O');
```

Updated method for supporting ascending and descending orders.

```
$.fn.sortTable = function (opt) {
    var sort = typeof opt.sortType !== 'undefined' ? opt.sortType : 'asc',
        cls = opt.cls;
    if (!cls) return;

    var $tr = this.find('tbody').children().sort(function(a, b){
       return $(a).find('.' + cls).text() > $(b).find('.' + cls).text();
    });

    if (sort === 'des') {
       $tr = $tr.toArray().reverse();
    }
    this.find('tbody').append($tr);
}

$('table').sortTable({
    cls: 'N',    // className of the cells
    sortType: 'des'  // order 'asc' || 'des' 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Af7mG/

Comment: Very elegant.  Is there a way to reverse this (sort descending?) and still keep the a title row at the top?

Comment: Unfortunately, when sorting DESC, it moves the header row to the bottom of the table.  To fix that I just put a table above this generated one that contains the header and altered your piece of art to work with a table ID.  It also seems to have some problems in GC and IE, but I like FF so I'm ok with that.